# ¿Cómo buscar y eliminar filas de archivo csv en base a que una columna cumpla una condición?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

---

Hace tiempo vengo trabajando en un proyecto en Python utilizando, en gran parte, la biblioteca *Pandas*. En mi proyecto, se van a mostrar listas que son resultados de un archivo .CSV.

Archivo CSV:

> Grabados,Cilindros,Almacenamiento,Estado,Fecha
>   10005,1,T53,GRABADO,01/11/2017 10015,1,Q06,DESGRABADO,01/11/2017

El archivo tendrá más de 4000 datos.

Me preguntaba como puedo hacer para que, el usuario pueda ingresar el nombre de un dato almacenado en la columna `Grabados`, el programa lo busque y elimine toda su fila respectiva de forma permanente.

Ejemplo:

> Ingrese el Grabado a eliminar --> 10015

Entonces, el programa busca el grabado 10015 y lo elimina del archivo CSV permanentemente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mi parecer, son dos cosas distintas. Pandas se va encargar de editar en memoria la tabla de datos que representa ese dataframe, por lo que tendrás que reguardar el archivo csv.

es decir, algo como

```
df_filtered = dataframe[dataframe["Grabados"] != numero_a_buscar]
df_filtered.to_csv("archivo.csv")
```

Esto lo que hace es:

1. Cargas Archivo
2. Te quedas con todos los rows que no aplican
3. Lo guardas, en esa misma ruta

Pero como mencionas, que quieres eliminarlo tal cual, no veo para que usar pandas. Como lo hace el colega acá: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454336/delete-some-rows-of-a-csv-in-place

```
import csv

with open("original.csv", "rb") as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f))

with open("original.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in data:
        if row[0] != numero_del_grabado_a_filtrar:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Y listo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias y perdón por las Molestias :) !

Comment: No es molestia, a las órdenes (: